# Preserving relationships when re-linking tables in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Once upon a time, you could take a set of tables in  Access re-link them to a new database (test to production, for example) and it would preserve the table relationships.  As of the latest change to Access 2016, relationships are removed when you do this.

Comment: How access works now or 20 years ago in this regards has not changed - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The way access works in this regards has not changed in 20 years.

To create a table, or index, or relationship? This is ALWAYS done in the back end. The act of "linking" does not change or even touch anything in the back end database that you link to.

And you can't change or modify relationships in the front end. What would happens if 3 different people linked to the same back end? (could they all have different relationships setup? If that could occur, then no type of enforced relationships would be possible in access.

As a result, any display of the relationships between tables in the front end that is doing the linking amounts to NOTHING MORE THEN A PRETTY PICTURE!

In other words, if you link, then access may or may not show the relationships in the relationships windows. Regardless of what is displayed, the viewing, the changing, the setup of relationships is ALWAYS done in the back end - what the front ends have or display in the relationships windows is 100% ignored, does not matter, and is not used.

You can for kicks and fun add tables in the front end for your viewing pleasure, and as you drop in tables, access will usually display the relationships used, but they only amount to a pretty picture. Because as noted, many different front ends can link to a database, then who or what would be controlling the relationships if they could be all different? As noted and as result, what Access front ends show and display is 100% ignored by the front end. There is no concept or need of a relationship between linked tables in the the front end. If you do manage for your fun and games to have tables displayed in the front end (relationships window), then it is simply for fun and your viewing pleasure.

Those font ends have zero to do with setting up relationships.

If you use the Access UI to link to a back end and the links are NEW, then in most cases Access front end will show the existing relationships. If you messed around, or cleared out the front end, then  re-link will not always show the tables. You can simply add them or delete all your table links and then simply re-create the links.

No matter which means you use (some code, or the built in UI), the display of the relationships in the front end is moot, does not matter, and is not used by Access. The ONLY relationship window that matters is when you open up the back end database and define and manage relationships from that window - all front ends and what they show or have or do not have are 100% ALWAYS ignored and for any linked table the front end DOES NOT matter.

## Edit

As a general rule when I do link tables to a front end, launching the relationships windows does (should) show the existing relationships. However, as I noted, it only amounts to a pretty picture - it does not effect or change the actual relationships in the back end.

However, as pointed out in the comments? If you do have a defined relationship(s) in the front end? When you build a query, they will be used for the default join between such tables - and as pointed out, this can be a time saver. So it is fair to point out and admit on my part that you get somewhat "more" then just a picture - you do get default joins when using the query builder.

Comment: When you say "NOTHING MORE THEN (sic) A PRETTY PICTURE!" all loud and in our faces, you are wrong.  While setting relationships among linked tables Access does not change the relationships on the backend, it DOES help when crafting queries in the query designer using those linked tables.  If you replicate the relationships in Access to match the backend they can save time by creating left/right/inner joins, etc. for you.  So, they are indeed more than a pretty picture.

Comment: Sure, good point.  In context to define relationships? No, they don't help or change anything. However, sure, if we are to expand the context beyond the "act" of a defining a relationship? And we are to note that "hey when building a query, a defined relationship in the front end will default the join for you? As long as we are now expanding the context, switching the context and NOT talking about defining relationships? So talking about building some query that not limited to those relationships? sure good idea, but my post was already too long, and we do risk some confusing to the readers.

Comment: I have up-voted your comment! (and added to the edit comments to reflect this issue you kindly pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Use the External Data -> Relink External Tables path to relink tables.  After selecting a data source and editing it to change from test to production or vice versa, use Refresh to relink the tables to the new location.  Do not use Relink.

(The Relationship diagram is important to our users for building ad hoc queries.  It is not just a pretty picture.)

Comment: I feel like this is a good start but would be more helpful if you could pass, eg, the table name and the expected prefix/suffix as parameters

Comment: Using linked code will not address nor does it matter in the context of this question. Use of code to link tables does NOT change that access only uses the relationships in the back end, and ignores what you have in the front end.